# Duplicated scope ngSwitch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive - popup, that when activated it switches to its content.

Using:

```
 <div  my-popup="popup"></div>
```

Popup:

```
    <div ng-switch-when="true">Content</div>
```

This poup has a function, that parent can call.

```
 scope.popup = { id: 'ddd', fn: function () {} };
```

The problem is, that when I close and open popup, the fn function gets called 2 times, and if I close it again, and open it again, it gets called 3-times, .... n-times.

So function gets called as manny times as the popup has been opened. How to fix this?

Comment: please share your code, if it possible in fiddle

Comment: It is a lot of code. I found out, that in directive, when button is clicked, I send an event, and this event gets doubled,n-times. Do I have to clear events, when directive is destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was not a problem in scopes, it was a problem in events, it looks like I have to destroy events otherwise they duplicate